# How can I use Dropzone.js in my own function

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am having difficulties integrating Dropzone.js with my own ajax function, I don't know what I should do to use dropzone inside my ajax function.

This is my own ajax function code :

```
function _ajaxForm(formHandler){
var action = $(formHandler).attr('action');
$.post(action, $(formHandler).serialize(), function(data){
    // I want to submit my fields and my form upload using this function
}, 'json');}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do.

Comment: how can i integrate dropzone inside this function

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure your dropzone accordingly.

Using the [sending](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending) event you could do something like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  // Some default configurations
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  // Additional configurations needed for your ajax call
  url: "insertyoururlhere",
  init: function () {
      this.on("error", function (error, message) {
        //do something to handle the error
      });
      this.on("success", function (success, response) {
        //do something
      });
      this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
        //add any form data that you would have in your ajax function eg:
        //formData.append("id", 123);
      });
      this.on("complete", function () {
        this.removeAllFiles(true);
        //do something
      });
    }
});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073878/send-custom-data-with-dropzone-js-on-each-file-upload), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083240/send-formdata-using-dropzone-js-on-sendingmultiple) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472952/adding-more-data-to-dropzone-js-post) answer which might also help.